# Magical Record: How to fetch and display an NSDate entity attribute to a UILabel in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: core-data, nsdate, magicalrecord

I'm using MagicalRecord to store a list of dates and descriptions in a Core Data entity's attribute and I need to display them to a UILabel in a UITableViewCell. But my app crashes whenever I access the UITableViewController. I'm not sure why it crashes but I believe it's because of the NSDate object. Please help.

Time+CoreDataProperties.h

```
#import "Time.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Time (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) TimeDetails *timeDetails;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

UITableViewController

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndex:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

-(void) configureCell: (UITableViewCell *) cell atIndex:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    Time *time = self.times[indexPath.row];
    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:100];
    titleLabel.text = time.title;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSString *dateDetails = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:time.timeDetails.date];
    NSLog(@"Date is %@",dateDetails);
    UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    dateLabel.text = dateDetails;
}
```

Error message:-
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dateLabel2.'

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger? Can pinpoint on which line your program crashes?

Comment: It's crashing over here:-                                                                                        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: You need to register a cell with the `tableView` as in `[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];` you can put this line in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thanks simple_code, this does take care of the crashes. However, my UITableViewController is empty. It isn't displaying the attributes in the Time entity.

Comment: You need to add an implementation for `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Comment: Yes, I have that. 
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.times.count;
}

Comment: Hi simple_code, I'm pleased to say that the app is now working. I deleted the app from the simulator and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you have defined the cell, in your storyboard or an XIB, you have connected an outlet to a label but that outlet doesn't exist. The outlet is called `dateLabel2`.

Go through all the labels in the cell, check the outlet connections on them and remove any that are invalid.

Comment: Hi Wain, thanks. I found the outlet dateLabel2 and have subsequently deleted it. But I still can't display my attributes.

Comment: That's a different question. Unless it's still an undefined key exception